# App cannot further process disks / folder in Xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, uwp, file-handling

Hey I'm new to Xamarin and I'm hoping you guys could help me. Since there isn't a default folder-picker in xamarin, I want to implement it myself. The problem is that UWP as well as Android throw me this exception:

System.UnauthorizedAccessException
HResult=0x80070005
Nachricht = Access to the path 'C:\Users\imtt\AppData\Local\Packages\3ef1aa30-7ffe-4ece-84c7-d2eaf1f8634b_wvdsmkc2tee92\LocalState\Test\199.jpg' is denied.
Quelle = System.IO.FileSystem
Stapelüberwachung:
bei System.IO.FileSystem.DeleteFile(String fullPath)
bei System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
bei MinimalReproducibleExample.ViewModel.DeleteFiles() in C:\Users\imtt\source\repos\MinimalReproducibleExample\MinimalReproducibleExample\MinimalReproducibleExample\ViewModel.cs: Zeile107
bei Xamarin.Forms.Command.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object o)
bei Xamarin.Forms.Command.Execute(Object parameter)
bei Xamarin.Forms.ButtonElement.ElementClicked(VisualElement visualElement, IButtonElement ButtonElementManager)
bei Xamarin.Forms.Button.SendClicked()
bei Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.ButtonRenderer.OnButtonClick(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

Here's the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MinimalReproducibleExample.MainPage">
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Add Image" Command="{Binding AddImage}"/>
    <Button Text="Delete Images" Command="{Binding DeleteImages}"/>
    <Image Source="{Binding CreatedImage}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Here's the code-behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MinimalReproducibleExample
{
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
      public MainPage()
      {
        BindingContext = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
 }
```

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using Xamarin.Essentials;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace MinimalReproducibleExample
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private ImageSource image;
        private string fileFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Test");
        public ICommand AddImage { get; }
        public ICommand DeleteImages { get; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            AddImage = new Command(ShowFilePicker);
            DeleteImages = new Command(DeleteFiles);
        }

        public ImageSource CreatedImage
        {
            get => image;
            set
            {
                image = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public async void ShowFilePicker()
        {
            FilePickerFileType filePickerFileType = new FilePickerFileType(
                    new Dictionary<DevicePlatform, IEnumerable<string>> {
                        { DevicePlatform.iOS, new [] { "jpeg", "png", "mp3", "mpeg4Movie", "plaintext", "utf8PlainText", "html" } },
                        { DevicePlatform.Android, new [] { "image/jpeg", "image/png", "audio/mp3", "audio/mpeg", "video/mp4", "text/*", "text/html" } },
                        { DevicePlatform.UWP, new []{ "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.mp3", "*.mp4", "*.txt", "*.html" } }
                    });

            PickOptions pickOptions = new PickOptions
            {
                PickerTitle = "Wählen Sie eine oder mehrere Dateien aus",
                FileTypes = filePickerFileType,
            };

            IEnumerable<FileResult> pickedFiles = await FilePicker.PickMultipleAsync(pickOptions);
            List<FileResult> results = pickedFiles.ToList();

            if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (FileResult fileResult in results)
                {

                    using (Stream stream = await fileResult.OpenReadAsync())
                    {

                        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(fileFolder);

                        string directoryPath = directoryInfo.FullName;

                        string filepath = Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileResult.FileName);

                        try
                        {

                            byte[] bArray = new byte[stream.Length];

                            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                            {
                                stream.Read(bArray, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                                int length = bArray.Length;
                                fs.Write(bArray, 0, length);
                            }

                            CreatedImage = ImageSource.FromFile(filepath);
                        }
                        catch (Exception exc)
                        {
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void DeleteFiles()
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(fileFolder);

            foreach(string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                File.Delete(filePath);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I already gave my app the access to the filesytem via windows settings, also I gave the Android-part read and write access. I even gave the UWP-part "broadFileAccess" and even that didn't make the cut.

This intersects with another problem, where the UWP part can write files into a folder in "Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData", but it isn't allowed to delete the files in this folder.

Does this have something to do with the sandboxes of UWP and Android?

Comment: The matched folder of Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData  is local storage where in UWP platform. And it has full permission that could read write and delete file.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Thanks for your response, I added the code snippets for the file creation and the deletion.

Comment: I think the reason why you are not allowed to delete the file is that you did not flush and dispose the FileStream after writing. That make the file still in use.  please try call `Flush` `Dispose`

Comment: I have try use above code to create file and write string in it then delete it, all steps work as expect.  We can't reproduce your problem. can you share us with [mcve]?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I tried your Flush and Dispose approach. Sadly that didn't make the cut. Doesn't using ensure that all used resources in the using-block are freed?

Comment: Ok, Could you mind made simple sample that could reproduce this problem ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I added the minimal reproducible example. Even with that code I got the System.UnauthorizedAccessException. :(

Comment: I run you code, the problem is the file was used by image control, if disable ` CreatedImage = ImageSource.FromFile(filepath);`, it will not throw exception.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I tried your solution and that fixes the exception, but creates a new problem. How do I free the file resource before deleting? I need that image control to display the image.

Comment: We suggest you render image with stream but not create source from file directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> App cannot further process disks / folder in Xamarin

I tested with you code, the problem is the file was using by image control when you delete it, if we disable `CreatedImage = ImageSource.FromFile(filepath);` this line.  it will work as expect.

> I need that image control to display the image

We suggest you render image with stream but not create source from file directly.

**For example**

```
CreatedImage = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
```

Comment: The stream must be of type MemoryStream, a normal stream doesn't work